# erlang distributed programming

Tags: erlang

I have an application which has the following requirement.

During the running of my Erlang App. on the fly I need to start one or more remote nodes either on the local host or a remote host.

I have looked at the following options

1) For starting a remote node on the local host either use the slave module or the net_kernel:start() API.
However with the latter , there seems to be no way to specify options like boot script file name etc.

2) In any case I don't need the slave configuration as I need to mimic similar behaviour of nodes spawned on local as
well as remote hosts. In my current setup, I dont have permissions to rsh to the remote host. The workaround i can think of is to have
a default node running on the remote host so as to enable remote node creation either through spawn or rpc:async_call and os:cmd
combination

Is there any other API interface to start erl ?

I am not sure this is the best or the cleanest way to solve this problem and I would like to know the Erlang approach to the same?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would like to clarify that net_kernel:start() is used to convert a non distributed node to distributed node (already running node) and not to start a remote node. So cannot take boot scripts or any other options.

Answer (score 0):

There is [pool](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/pool.html) module which might help you, however it utilizes `slave` module (thereof `rsh`).